# How vulnerable are SSDs to power failures compared to HDDs?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, storage

Are SSDs as vulnerable to data corruption as Mechanical HDDs during power outages? Since SSDs have no moving parts, I'm assuming that they can handle power failures better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Are SSDs prone to power failures as well?

Yes, SSDs can be vulnerable to powers cuts just like HDDs.
The vulnerability of storage media to power cuts is during write operations.
There's even anecdotal evidence that (older?) SSDs are more susceptible than HDDs to problems from power cuts:  https://www.extremetech.com/computing/169124-the-mysteriously-disappearing-drive-are-power-outages-killing-your-ssds

> Since they have no moving parts, I'm assuming that they can handle power failures better.

Faulty assumption.

An HDD is likely to lose only a sector's worth of data due to a power cut.  Otherwise a modern HDD is designed to handle sudden loss of power.  For example the HDD maintains reserve power or retractors to execute an immediate seek to safely park the R/W heads when the power is cut.

But flash chips require a erasure of a block (of many pages/sectors) before a page write can actually be performed.
So in some respects it can actually be worse, since erasing a block could involve saving/coping many pages/sectors of valid data, aka [write amplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_amplification) , so more valid data could be vulnerable.

SSDs trade mechanical complexity with logical complexity.
In order to accomplish efficient writes and wear-leveling, a logical layer of sector mapping is imposed over the physical NAND chips, i.e. a flash translation layer.  To order to avoid catastrophic loss of this crucial mapping, SSDs can employ reserve power sources, e.g. holdup capacitors, to ensure completion of crucial operations on detection of a power cut.
However as this [manufacturer's document](https://www.micron.com/about/blog/2017/february/unexpected-power-loss-and-how-ssd-can-help?sc_lang=zh-tw) states, SSDs do not have equal capabilities in self-protection from power cuts.
So generalizations about all SSDs and power loss are likely to be inaccurate.

But the vulnerability of storage media to power cuts is minimized by using [journaled filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system) such as NTFS, ext4, and UBIFS.  Since modern operating systems have a preference  for using a journaled filesystem, you are unlikely to encounter filesystem integrity issues caused by data loss during a power cut.
However this can only protect against loss of pending writes that did not complete.  The storage media is expected to accurately preserve previously written data.
In this regard SSDs could have a weakness that has to be compensated with self-protection capabilities that varies between manufacturer brands & models.

Comment: Many SSD have one or more extra capacitors to handle this situation.  SSD also take a faction of the time to write data so chances are they still come out ahead. HDD >6ms SSD around 0.1ms I wonder who will finish first.

Comment: *"HDD >6ms"* -- Where do you get such a bogus number? At 7200 RPM with  63 sectors per track, a sector write could take 132 usec.  Any seek and rotational overhead prior to the actual write operation does not put the disk medium at risk.  The danger of corrupted medium is a power cut during the actual write operation. With write cache involved you never know when the actual write operation will occur.  Pending writes that never complete is a fact of life that the OS must deal with regardless of the type of device.

Comment: The 6ms includes the seek time to find the correct sector.  Its listed on every hard drive. https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822146116  The seek time says less than 12ms, if it were 132usec then they would have certainly used a lower number.