# Besides HDD partial writes, downsides to abrupt power off

Tags: laptop, desktop-computer

Are there any downsides to turning off a computer power abruptly, besides incomplete HDD writes?

To enumerate the losses I know from my research and the answer here so far-

"Soft" loss:

- HDD Data
- ?

"Hard" loss (of hardware)

- HDD head crash (from an answer below)
- ?

Comment: Questions should be based on appropriate research, your question lacks it. Also it's not clear what's the scope of your question only HDD, while computer?

Comment: For SDDs refer also to this: https://superuser.com/questions/1155059/is-it-okay-if-i-just-turn-off-power-if-i-have-a-ssd

Comment: Re research : did it occur to you that my original question would have been downsides to abrupt off but I researched the loss of hdd data? Re scope: did it occur to you to perhaps see the tags?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Thanks, looks like all 3 talk only about data loss due to incomplete writes ... ?

Comment: This is way too broad...  and so far it trigger very bad incomplete and outdated answers as well. What specific problem are you trying to solve with this question what are your specific system specs? If not further specified I vote to close and delete.

Comment: I see two upvotes and failure to close yet, so boo. Go to hell. This is a very good question and you anal retentive retards are unnecessarily creating problems.

Answer (score 0):

The most notable risk of physical damage would be a head crash, which is when the drive head crashes onto the magnetic platter inside an HDD, causing physical damage to the surface of the platter itself.

*This problem has been engineered out of existence and is no longer a concern with modern hard hard drives but is worth mentioning as it once accounted for some of the most serious physical damage that could occur to computer's hardware during abrupt power failures.*

These days, there is no risk of physical damage to computer hardware from a power outage (assuming it is not accompanied by a power surge). The main concern would be data loss (i.e. unsaved files) and data corruption (in the case of data that is being written to disc being interrupted.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks (not sure who would downvote this!)

Comment: This is not completely inaccurate as very, very old hard drives used to have to be “parked” before powering them off. That is no longer true. Hard drives store enough energy either through capacitors or magnets to park the head automatically when the power is lost. Modern hard drive heads will never crash due to a power failure.

Comment: I've updated my answer. That's a good point.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to not just turn off a modern computer is that there are a lot of files on the HD (or SSD) whose contents are cached as you are running, and those caches don't get written to HD except for during a clean shutdown. Those updates won't make it to stable storage, and often even worse, only some of them do, so you have inconsistent data. Depending on the application or system component, this can be cleaned up / recovered from (in Unix systems, this is what fsck does), but sometimes it can't.

Comment: If you had omitted the silly head crash info, I would have upvoted this answer.

Comment: You're right - I took out the silly head crash info, which only matters if you have silly spinning disks (which, to be fair, still exist on many servers, due to $/GB), but that's not what this question is about.

Comment: Head crashes aren't just from spinning disks, but from VERY OLD spinning disks.

Comment: This question *indeed* is about everything that can go wrong but @music2myear thanks for pointing out the distinction about "VERY OLD". So you're saying fine with new HDDs? (10year old?)

Comment: The question is about everything that can go wrong due to abrupt power off. I'm having trouble finding a specific record, but I'd guess the age is closer to 20 years rather than 10. Head crashes can still happen on spinning disks if the drive is moved suddenly with a lot of force while it is spinning. But drives even 12 years ago had sensors that would automatically park the heads when they detected a drop, securing the head before the device hit the ground, which is what would generate sufficient force. Limiting ourselves to power failure, the heads are pulled back into park by magnets.